# How do I display all items from a table in a database using a partial view with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a list of categories to display on the home page of an ASP.NET MVC app, I am making use of an Index view and a partial view. One of the categories in the `Category` table displays, but the other 3 are ignored, can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Here is the partial:

```
@model IEnumerable<MenuItem>

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="text-success"> @Model.FirstOrDefault().Category.Name </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is the code from the view itself

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Category)
{
    <div class="row" id="menu-wrapper">
        <partial name="_ThumbnailAreaPartial" model="@Model.MenuItem.Where(u=>u.Category.Name.Equals(category.Name))" />
    </div>
}
```

I can't figure out why only one item is being displayed.

Thank you

Comment: `@Model.FirstOrDefault()` will show the first item only. Why you have partial view? to display all the categories in one partial view? in that case you don't need `@foreach (var category in Model.Category)` you need to have the foreach loop in the partial view.

Comment: I see the grammar police are at work with my post; if this were something formal, where I wanted to make a great impression, those errors never would have existed. I just got over covid, so I haven't been able to reply. 
In the other categories, the issue was that nothing existed in the database. The app is written not to show any category unless it has something.
This is one of those "smaller" details I seem to miss sometimes. I've found at times, just asking a question can help me see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: One other thing I would note (in case any newer developers read this in the future), some times just by asking a question, you can figure out what is causing the issue, which is what happened in my case. I would've responded sooner; I just had the illness previously noted. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

fix view

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Category)
    {
        <div class="row" id="menu-wrapper">
            <partial name="_ThumbnailAreaPartial" 
model="@Model.MenuItem.Where(u=>u.Category.Name.Equals(category.Name)).FirstOrDefault()" />
        </div>
    }
```

and partial view

```
@model MenuItem

@if (Model!=null  && Model.Category!=null )
{
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="text-success"> @Model.Category.Name </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```